# Procedure to ensure herbicide uptake in Japanese knotweed

Tags: weed-control, herbicide

I am planning to eradicate a stand of Japanese knotweed by injection of imazapyr. This bamboo-like plant develops a rhizome system far below the ground and the only way to kill it is allow it to absorb a herbicide into the rhizomes.

The problem is that there are two basic approaches. One approach is to cut off the stalks, then inject the herbicide into the resulting cup-like cavity. The other approach is to use a syringe to inject the herbicide into the stalk without cutting it first.

Which approach will be more effective in ensuring that the herbicide reaches the rhizomes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because weed control is not in the purview of this site. Ask at [gardening.se] instead, or do your own study and try both methods on separate plants.

Comment: @MattDMo It's a biological question. Just because the question has a practical application does not mean it is not about biology. I want to understand how imazapyr is absorbed in this kind of plant and what conditions are conducive for the toxin to reach the rhizomes of the plant. That is a biology problem.

Comment: @ImprisonedRhesus It is a "biological" question but it is a better fit at [gardening.se]. If your question was more about the actual physiology and molecular mechanism then this question would have been a better fit here. Your question is more about how to effectively use the herbicide and that is a matter of gardening practice.